# LuaJava what is the definition of status code when calling LuaState.pcall(..)

Tags: lua, luajava

I am trying to call a function in LuaJava.  I am always getting back 5 as the status code.
So int ok=LuaState.pcall(1,1,-1); always returns 5.  calling the same function from the command line works fine.  What is the meaning of 5 as a return code?

---

```
 /**
   * error while running the error handler function.
   */
  final public static Integer LUA_ERRERR    = new Integer(5);
```

Looking at LuaState.java

Comment: possible duplicate of [LuaJava Error in Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621471/luajava-error-in-error-handling)